# ‘Fail due to unhealthy allocation' deploying django site using fly.io

Tags: python, django, web, deployment, web-deployment

I am super new to deployment and django and I’m trying to deploy a simple django site without database with fly.io. I’ve been getting errors for 4 days and would really appreciate it if anyone can help! The error is below

```
==> Creating release
--> release v3 created

--> You can detach the terminal anytime without stopping the deployment
==> Monitoring deployment
Logs: https://fly.io/apps/chaplinhuang/monitoring

 1 desired, 1 placed, 0 healthy, 1 unhealthy [restarts: 2] [health checks: 1 total]
Failed Instances

Failure #1

Instance
ID              PROCESS VERSION REGION  DESIRED STATUS  HEALTH CHECKS   RESTARTS        CREATED  
00d71cce        app     3       ord     run     pending 1 total         2               1m0s ago

Recent Events
TIMESTAMP               TYPE            MESSAGE                         
2022-12-26T02:05:54Z    Received        Task received by client        
2022-12-26T02:05:54Z    Task Setup      Building Task Directory        
2022-12-26T02:06:25Z    Started         Task started by client         
2022-12-26T02:06:27Z    Terminated      Exit Code: 3                   
2022-12-26T02:06:27Z    Restarting      Task restarting in 1.042869453s
2022-12-26T02:06:44Z    Started         Task started by client         
2022-12-26T02:06:46Z    Terminated      Exit Code: 3                   
2022-12-26T02:06:46Z    Restarting      Task restarting in 1.11932696s 

2022-12-26T02:07:03Z   [info][2022-12-26 02:07:03 +0000] [525] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 525
2022-12-26T02:07:03Z   [info][2022-12-26 02:07:03 +0000] [525] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
2022-12-26T02:07:03Z   [info]Traceback (most recent call last):
2022-12-26T02:07:03Z   [info]  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 589, in spawn_worker
2022-12-26T02:07:03Z   [info]    worker.init_process()
2022-12-26T02:07:03Z   [info]  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 134, in init_process
2022-12-26T02:07:03Z   [info]    self.load_wsgi()
2022-12-26T02:07:03Z   [info]  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 146, in load_wsgi
2022-12-26T02:07:03Z   [info]    self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
2022-12-26T02:07:03Z   [info]  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
2022-12-26T02:07:03Z   [info]    self.callable = self.load()
2022-12-26T02:07:03Z   [info]  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 58, in load
2022-12-26T02:07:03Z   [info]    return self.load_wsgiapp()
2022-12-26T02:07:03Z   [info]  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 48, in load_wsgiapp
2022-12-26T02:07:03Z   [info]    return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
2022-12-26T02:07:03Z   [info]  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 359, in import_app
2022-12-26T02:07:03Z   [info]    mod = importlib.import_module(module)
2022-12-26T02:07:03Z   [info]  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
2022-12-26T02:07:03Z   [info]    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
2022-12-26T02:07:03Z   [info]  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
2022-12-26T02:07:03Z   [info]  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
2022-12-26T02:07:03Z   [info]  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 992, in _find_and_load_unlocked
2022-12-26T02:07:03Z   [info]  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
2022-12-26T02:07:03Z   [info]  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
2022-12-26T02:07:03Z   [info]  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
2022-12-26T02:07:03Z   [info]  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1004, in _find_and_load_unlocked
2022-12-26T02:07:03Z   [info]ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'demo'
2022-12-26T02:07:04Z   [info][2022-12-26 02:07:04 +0000] [520] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
2022-12-26T02:07:04Z   [info][2022-12-26 02:07:04 +0000] [520] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
2022-12-26T02:07:04Z   [info]Starting clean up.
--> v3 failed - Failed due to unhealthy allocations - no stable job version to auto revert to and deploying as v4 

--> Troubleshooting guide at https://fly.io/docs/getting-started/troubleshooting/
Error abort
```

My current fly.toml

```
# fly.toml file generated for chaplinhuang on 2022-12-24T18:27:36+08:00

app = "chaplinhuang"
kill_signal = "SIGINT"
kill_timeout = 5
processes = []

[env]
  PORT = "8080"

[experimental]
  allowed_public_ports = []
  auto_rollback = true

[[services]]
  http_checks = []
  internal_port = 8080
  processes = ["app"]
  protocol = "tcp"
  script_checks = []
  [services.concurrency]
    hard_limit = 25
    soft_limit = 20
    type = "connections"

  [[services.ports]]
    force_https = true
    handlers = ["http"]
    port = 80

  [[services.ports]]
    handlers = ["tls", "http"]
    port = 443

  [[services.tcp_checks]]
    grace_period = "30s"
    interval = "15s"
    restart_limit = 0
    timeout = "2s"

[[statics]]
  guest_path = "/app/public"
  url_prefix = "/static/"
```

My current Dockerfile

```
ARG PYTHON_VERSION=3.10-slim-buster

FROM python:${PYTHON_VERSION}

ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

RUN mkdir -p /code

WORKDIR /code

COPY requirements.txt /tmp/requirements.txt

RUN set -ex && \
    pip install --upgrade pip && \
    pip install -r /tmp/requirements.txt && \
    rm -rf /root/.cache/

COPY . /code/

RUN python manage.py collectstatic --noinput

EXPOSE 8000 

# replace demo.wsgi with <project_name>.wsgi
CMD ["gunicorn", "--bind", ":8000", "--workers", "2", "demo.wsgi"]
```

I have tried to change the port to 8080, but cannot change ip address to 0.0.0.0, what should I do? Any input is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

In your case you're exposing the 8000 port, but in your fly.toml, you need to set the same port as well, something inside of services:

```
  [[services.ports]]
    force_https = true
    handlers = ["http"]
    port = 8000
```

Answer (score -1):

This error is come for the port but your ports is right and logs has reported that
"ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'demo'" .the app could not find the module demo. It's also a reason.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).